# Slow SBT start up with many projects

Tags: performance, sbt, profiling

I have a SBT project with ~40 subprojects.
There are several plugins, the largest of which are Play and sbt-native-packager. There are no global plugins.

On some fairly beefy hardware, start up (after the first time) takes 20-25 s.
I know that it is not all due to JVM startup, since a small project (pure overhead) starts in 3-4s.

How can I find out why sbt is taking longer to start in the larger project?

I've tried sbt -Dsbt.task.timings=true, but it doesn't include what is taking a bulk of the time. After the last timing prints, but before

> Set current project to example (in build file:/home/paul/lucid/example/)

there is a 15s pause.

How can I find what causes the slow start up?

Answer (score 2):

Try creating `project/debug.sbt`:

```
logLevel := Level.Debug
```

and see what you find. Often it's the compilation of the build files if you have `project/*.scala`.

Comment: Are SBT files faster or are they essentially Scala files at the end of the day?

Comment: They are also going to be compiled. To save time one should make it into a published plugin.

Comment: "start up (after the first time)" By that I mean that all project/*.scala files are compiled.